# Date parameter format problem

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008

On a report parameter of data type DateTime, when I select a date using the date picker, it uses my local format (dd/mm/yyyy), but then I get an error that the value is not valid for the data type, but as soon as I enter a date in the US formt (mm/dd/yyyy), the report runs but the date gets displayed correctly in my local format.  What is going on here?

Comment: What is the "Localization" >> "Language" properties of the RDL set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application ran by a different user account (eg networkservice localservice etc) may have different locality settings. This will effect how datetime objects are parsed to strings.